# Random signature in Outlook (2010)

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm currently using Microsoft's Office Outlook 2010 as an email client, and I would like to have a random signature. I know there are some third part softwares which can do it, but my client is in a closed environment and I can't use them.

I know it can be done with a simple VB Macro, however I don't know how to write it (not a VB scripter [luckily]), nor what functions to use. I just need a simple macro to place a random line (I can find a way to look from a file later, but currently I need something to display a random signature, or even a macro just to write to a signature).

I'd appreciate any help in the issue, even to refer me to some helpful guiding links.

Sincerely.
Me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is handle the `Application_ItemSend` event.

Put a distinctive string into your signature such as `RANDOM_GOES_HERE`, then in your ItemSend event you can use the `HTMLBody` and `TextBody` properties, along with search/replace, to replace the string `RANDOM_GOES_HERE` with a random piece of text.

Comment: Can I do it when I open a new mail instead of sending one?

Plus, how exactly do I handle it? just write in the macro "Sub Application_ItemSend...End Sub" ?

Comment: Turns out on the Mac version there is a Random option...I need to search first and ask questions later.